# How to add the result of a custom query to the Django Admin Site change_form template?

Tags: django, django-admin

My web application manages hospitalizations and specialist examinations. Some of these exams may have been performed during a hospitalization, but I have no connection between the hospitalizations and the specialist exams.

When the user modifies the data of an exam, I would like him to see at the bottom of the page all the admissions started before the exam and finished after the exam, because one of them could be the admissions where the exam was taken.

This is a piece of code from the models.py file, which I translated into English:

```
    class Hospitalization(models.Model):
        start_date = models.DateField()
        stop_date = models.DateField()

    class Exam(models.Model):
        exam_date = models.DateField()
```

In which file should I write the code that makes the query? How do I pass the query result to the change_form template?

I copied the change_form.html file into the templates\myapp\model_name folder and I am ready to override the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: kindly show code you had tried before.

Comment: @Alviandoh, I edited the question with a simple translated piece of code.